# AngularJS splash screen with $resource promiese

Tags: angularjs, splash-screen

I have an application where some data must be loaded(ajax) before actual application is rendered. I would like to show some splash screen to provide feedback to user, that something is still loading.

Where/How should I call initialize method of that services?

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.service('DataSet1', function(){
    this.initialize = function(){
        //.. returns promiese
    }
});
app.service('DataSet2', function(){
    this.initialize = function(){
        //.. returns promiese
    }
});
app.service('DataSet3', function(){
    this.initialize = function(){
        //.. returns promiese
    }
});
```

I would appretiate any help how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit: adding jsbin example

#### new answer

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/nileriweqo/edit?html,js,console,output)

This new approach, by passing in `{showLoader: true}` as part of the request option, you can specify which requests to show the "loading..." panel for.

This leverages httpInterceptor and factory to keep track of pending requests.

#### old answer (loading will show for any pending request)

```
http.pendingRequests.length !== 0;
```

Be sure http is exposed in your scope null.

```
<spinner ng-if="http.pendingRequests.length"></spinner>
```

Comment: Thanks but Where should I put that code? And how do I prevent actuall rendering of app ?